# "'DataTypes' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

Trying to do a quick setup of an app with Sequelize in TypeScript, and I'm already running into this issue defining basic models. It likely has something to do with the way I've set up Typescript and/or the types library for Sequelize.

```js
const User = sequelize.define("User", {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
});

export default User;
```

Results in the TS compiler complaining with:

> 'DataTypes' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

All I can see is the `DataTypes` interface in the Sequelize types file with an annotating comment describing it as a "class". Why isn't the compiler resolving the concrete type? This is all freshly set up.

Investigated the type definitions, reinstalled `@types/sequelize` and `sequelize` independently, futzed with some TS configurations. Expected `DataTypes` to be a concrete type, which it is, somewhere.

Comment: How are you importing it? What versions of TypeScript, Sequelize, and @types/sequelize are you using?

Comment: `import { DataTypes } from "sequelize";` - it seems if I require it it does work, though the type information is lost. What's that about? I've forgotten everything I ever knew about JS modules.

Comment: Go to definition of `DataTypes` (Ctrl+click) and check what you actually import, a type or an object. Try `let a = DataTypes.STRING`

Comment: I have created a stackblitz and it does not complain at all. You can fork it and show what is not working for you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-euavjf?file=User.ts

Comment: @SvetoslavPetkov that configuration is completely identical to mine down to versions and the `esnext` target. I'm absolutely baffled. The difference is that in my case, TS is getting its type information for `DataTypes` from `@types/sequelize/index.d.ts`, whereas in the case of your example it is coming from `data-types.d.ts` from the types file provided by the actual `sequelize` library and they are entirely different things. The type in `data-types.d.ts` is a concrete type whereas `DataTypes` in `@types/sequelize/index.d.ts` is an interface.

Comment: I was able to fix this by setting `moduleResolution` to node and removing `@types/sequelize`. I would really like to know what happened here.